# duplicate every row multiple times in linux

Tags: linux, row

I have a data file

```
a b c
d e f
g h i
```

and want to dublicate every row x times. So if x was chosen as 2 I would like to get:

```
a b c
a b c
d e f
d e f
g h i
g h i
```

Is there an easy and fast way to do this with simple linux commands? Otherwise any other ideas how to realize it, e.g. with Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `perl` you can do this

```
perl -ne 'for$i(0..2){print}' your_input_file
```

and with `awk`

```
awk '{for(i=0;i<2;i++)print}' your_input_file
```

and with `sed`

```
sed -n '{p;p;}' your_input_file
```